# Swift 2.0 Dictionary KVC-Extension

Tags: dictionary, swift2, protocols, kvc

I am trying to implement a dictionary extension to conform to a KVC protocol:

```
protocol KVCodeable {
    func valueForKeyPath(keyPath: String) -> AnyObject?
}
```

Reason for doing so, I'd like to be able to get values from either NSManagedObjects or Dictionarys.

so I'd define a model object:

```
var modelObject: KVCodeable?
```

later on, I'm accessing that model object, trying to get a value:

```
let value: AnyObject? = modelObject?.valueForKeyPath(keyPath)
```

My model object is an NSManagedObject in some cases and in a few other cases, it's a swift Dictionary or derivations thereof.

```
extension NSManagedObject: KVCodeable {} //already done

                 : KVCodeable
                   \/
extension Dictionary where Key: String {
    func valueForKeyPath(keyPath: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return self[keyPath]
    }
}
```

How can I define my extension of dictionary where Key: String to conform to KVCodable?

thanks
Ronny

Answer (score 2):

The problem cannot be solved as a whole, but there are two semi solutions:

1) Extending all dictionaries:

```
extension Dictionary: KVCodeable {
    func valueForKeyPath(keyPath: String) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let key = keyPath as? Key else { return nil }
        return self[key] as? AnyObject
    }
}
```

2) Extend only specific dictionaries but you have to remove the conformance to `KVCodeable`:

```
// You have to make this protocol since:
// extension Dictionary where Key == String { ... }
// is currently not allowed
protocol StringType { var string: String { get } }
extension String: StringType { var string: String { return self } }

extension Dictionary where Key: StringType, Value: AnyObject {
    func valueForKeyPath(keyPath: String) -> AnyObject? {
        guard let key = keyPath as? Key else { return nil }
        return self[key] as? AnyObject
    }
}
```

In conclusion the first one is probably the best one. Otherwise you could also make the function a throwing one in order to catch "wrong" dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but is not the nicest solution.

```
extension Dictionary:KVCodeable {
    public func valueForKeyPath(keyPath: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return self[keyPath as! Key] as? AnyObject
    }
}
```

Comment: true, working but potentially dangerous...
one could do this:
if let k = key as? Key {
            return self[k] as? AnyObject
}

Comment: but essentially this will extend all dictionary types, I was aiming for finding the one of type <String, AnyObject>

Comment: Yep, I guess maybe is a Swift limitation, for now. I can't get it to work only for  a specific Dictionary type.